# htmlspecialchars does not work inside data-content

Tags: php, html, security, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

I'm using bootstrap select to display categories and i'm sanitizing those categories with htmlspecialchars but for some reason when it is inside data-content atribute it doesn't work beacuse i have a category named  and the browser interprets it as has being a real html tag rather that a string. I have tried to use htmlentitites but it does not work either... I have also though about using urlencode but since i am using bootstrap select i don't know where to uncode it...

Here is my code:

```
"<option value='$row[id]' data-content='<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-stop\" 
style=\"color:$row[cor]\"></span> <span style=\"text-align:left\"> 
".htmlspecialchars("$row[nome]",ENT_QUOTES)." 
</span>'>".htmlspecialchars("$row[nome]",ENT_QUOTES)."</option>";
```

[As you can see all categories are showing (they have wierd names for testing purposes) but the last one that has the name of `</a>` is not showing up and has you can see in the source the `</a>` is being interpred as html and not as a string as the other categorie names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x8v6.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Does it echo `$row[nome]` ?

Comment: What is the output of all this, and how does it show up on your page and how would you *like* it to show up on your page?

Comment: Basicly it interprets the </a> as html and i want it to interpert it as a string and not as html

Comment: It does echo $row[nome] but the problem is when it is something like </a> it interpert it as being a html tag and not a string

Comment: There's no `</a>` anywhere we can see. Give us the full output of that PHP code.

Comment: Try `htmlentities()` instead. And don't put quotes around the `$row['nome']` when used inside a function. It's confusing this way.

Comment: The desired output is a list of all the avaiable categories as strings and not as html.

Comment: htmlentities() doen't work either...

Comment: Don't *describe* what the output is, ***show us!***

Comment: I have uploaded a picture of the problem...

Comment: You're creating `<option>` elements here. Your screenshot shows a bunch of `<li>`s. There's a big ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ in between that…

Comment: Exactly! And that big in between is bootstap-select... And i can not figure out how it can pass through bootstrap-select and work...

Comment: `data-content` takes HTML. You need to HTML-encode that value because it's an HTML attribute so as not to screw up the HTML attribute syntax. If you want that value, or some value within that value, not to be interpreted as HTML, you need to HTML-encode that yet again. So, HTML-encode the content you want to be shown as text, and then HTML-encode the entire `data-content` attribute value in order to preserve its syntax.

Comment: And where do i decode it?

Comment: You simply don't.

Comment: And to encode do i use `urlencode()` ?

Comment: So, let me see if i got this right, is this what you mean: `data-content='".urlencode('<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-stop\" style=\"color:$row[cor]\"></span> <span style=\"text-align:left\"> '.urlencode($row['nome']).'</span>')."`

Comment: The code that i used above is not working... what am i doing wrong? It doesn't seem to be decoding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `<` is interpreted as the start of an HTML tag.
A `&lt;` is the HTML-encoded entity which will be interpreted as the character "<".

If you put something that looks like HTML into an attribute, you need to HTML-encode it to avoid breaking the HTML attribute. E.g., the attribute is surrounded by quotes, if you want to have quotes inside the attribute as a value those need to be `&quot;`:

```
attribute="&quot;value&quot;"
```

[bootstrap-select](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-select) uses the value of the `data-content` attribute as HTML.
So `data-content="&lt;span&gt;"` will end up as the HTML element `<span>`.

If you want it to end up as the *text* "<span>", you need to provide HTML that renders the text "<span>", which is `&lt;span&gt;`. Since you're putting that into an HTML attribute, you need to HTML-encode *that* to:

```
data-content="&amp;lt;span&amp;gt;"
```

☝️ This is the correctly HTML-encoded value (because it's in an attribute) of `&lt;span&gt;`, which when interpreted as HTML (as [bootstrap-select](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-select) will do) renders as the text "<span>".

So:

```
$attrTemplate = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop" style="color:%s"></span>
                 <span style="text-align:left">%s</span>';
$attr = sprintf($attrTemplate, htmlspecialchars($row['cor']), htmlspecialchars($row['nome']));

$optionTemplate = '<option value="%s" data-content="%s">%s</option>';
printf($optionTemplate, htmlspecialchars($row['id']), htmlspecialchars($attr), htmlspecialchars($row['nome']));
```

As you can see, everything that goes into HTML that you want to preserve as is must be HTML-encoded (here using `htmlspecialchars`).

Also see [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Comment: I think i'm missing something: `data-content='&lt;span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-stop\" style=\"color:". htmlspecialchars($row['cor']) ."\"&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span style=\"text-align:left\"&gt;". htmlspecialchars($row['nome']) ."&lt;/span&gt;'` I just don't know what... I did not realy undertood the last part of your code...

Comment: Yes, the innermost `$row['nome']` needs to be HTML-encoded *twice*. If you'd literally use my code above, this would all be much easier.

Comment: I realy did not understood it because i don't understand from where the %s comes from...

Comment: http://www.php.net/sprintf (Look at the examples. No need to comprehend the entire description.)

Comment: The way *you're* doing it you'd have to do `htmlspecialchars(htmlspecialchars($row['nome']))`. The way I'm showing it is much more comprehensible and less error prone once you understand some basic `sprintf`.

Comment: So let me see if i understand this, i echo out the printf part?

Comment: Yes, `printf` outputs the final HTML. As the name implies, `printf` already prints, as opposed to `sprintf` which *returns*.

Comment: The problem is it outputting %s as the name of the category... Here is my attempt at using your code: https://ibb.co/hHTXGJ

Comment: No, it's not: https://3v4l.org/cevBF What you're doing is not my code. Instead of `printf(...)` you seem to want `$output .= sprintf(...)`.

Comment: I managed to understand how sprintf works! And now i was able to use understand your code! Thank you!